# can nServiceBus be integrated into Winform?

Tags: nservicebus

I see all sample from nServiceBus to be a standalone process, so can it be integrated with winform?
if yes, where can i find samples?

Comment: any sample with full source code ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you want the generic host to run as a winform you need to pass it /gui on the command line.

Comment: I mean, if i already have a winform app, i wanna emply nServiceBus to pub/sub message, how to do this, since your nServiceBus has so little document. thanks for the great messaging framework.

Comment: Then in your main method of your program class, you'd write something similar to the following:

NServiceBus.Configure.With()
    .SpringBuilder()
    .XmlSerializer()
    .MsmqTransport()
        .PurgeOnStartup(true)
    .UnicastBus()
        .LoadMessageHandlers()
    .CreateBus()
    .Start();

You can see this in the AsyncPages sample, just make sure not to use "WithWeb()" in your WinForms app.

Hope that covers it for you.

Comment: thanks Udi Dahan. I am excited to directly communicate the writer. thousand thanks.

Answer (score 0):

You can just call nServiceBus class like usual in WinForm.